# How can I store customizable themes for different clients like posterous.com?

Tags: css, web-applications, posterous

What is the best way to store themes + css for different clients like posterous.com does?

Do they store entire css for each client? Is this sustainable for large number if clients?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking personalization.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx